# Getting array of one variable per object from API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

So I have the following in my API:

```
{
"rooms": [
    {
       "id": "01fa01fa5f685563",
      "name": "Main Bedroom",
      "meta": "{bedroom}"
    },
    {
      "id": "7bb6f6ec4dbed853",
      "name": "Laundry Room",
      "meta": "{laundry}"
    }
  ]
}
```

So now I want to get all the names under 'rooms' (in this case it would be "Main Bedroom" and "Laundry Room") as an array.

I have two .js files
One is called api.js

```
var api = class {
    static get baseUrl() {
    return "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/";
  }

  static get timeout() {
    return 60 * 1000;
  }
}

api.rooms = class {
  static get url() {
    return api.baseUrl + "rooms/";
  }

  static getRooms() {
       return $.ajax({
            url: api.room.url,
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            timeout: api.timeout
             .then(function(data) {
                 data.rooms.map(item => item.name);
               })

          }); 
    }
}
```

And then I have another .js called rooms.js where **I want to call this getRooms() function and then do something with the array of names I want to get from it**. How can I do this???
I though of something as simple as:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

          $("#title").text(api.rooms.getRooms()[0]);

   });
```

I'm just starting with APIs and JSON and that stuff. 
If anyone has a good tutorial I can watch or read it would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this. It iterates through the array and maps each element to the return value.

```js
const data = {
  "rooms": [{
      "id": "01fa01fa5f685563",
      "name": "Main Bedroom",
      "meta": "{bedroom}"
    },
    {
      "id": "7bb6f6ec4dbed853",
      "name": "Laundry Room",
      "meta": "{laundry}"
    }
  ]
};

const result = data.rooms.map(item => item.name);
console.log(result);
```

---

**Edit 1**:

Your `getRooms()` function seems okay (assuming the value for URL and timeout are correct), but you need to use `then()` to get results from it:

```
getRooms()
  .then(function(data) {
    data.rooms.map( ... );
  })
```

Comment: @Stackoverflowed -- In the callback of `map`, instead of just returning the `name`, you can return an object containing `id` and `name` both.